# Find integer numbers in string except numbers include % c#

Tags: c#, regex, string, digit

I need to find integer number in a string which includes one integer and one percentage number.

Example: 
price 3500 USD and discount 34% 
I need to extract 3500 only.

Currently I am using:

```
Regex.Match("price 3500 USD and discount 34%" , @"\d+");
```

But it doesnt extract 3500 only.

Comment: Please provide your attempts for solving this and show more detailed data.

Comment: Can you give some more information about the exact string structure and if it's per line etc.? Do you just need the numbers or also "USD" etc.? If you just want the numbers you could actually just split by space and extract all numbers that are not decimals.

Comment: @Bauss There is not any known structure for string, just it contains one digit and one decimal number, and I  just  need an integer number..

Comment: Are they all stored in one string and is there guaranteed to be spaces in between every number? "text 558181 text 9491 1499 14919 text" or could it be like "text38113 9391 text 193291text" ?

Comment: Yes they are all separated by space.

Comment: What `decimal number` are you talking about ?

Comment: @sln I mean percentage number.

Comment: Oh, my answer is screwed up then.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need regex for this. A simple Linq is enough

```
var numbers = inputstr.Split().Where(x => x.All(char.IsDigit)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Elegant C# solution.

Comment: For what it's worth, the validity of this answer depends on the interpretation of the criterion "find integer number in a string which includes one integer and one percentage number" -- in that the desired behavior is undefined when no percentage number is present. That is, does the OP mean "which may include" or "which must include"? That having been said, I agree, this is a very elegant solution. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Whitespace boundaries are the key here. This type of assertion construct
matches on BOS and EOS as well.

You can find integer numbers on whitespace boundaries like this -

```
 # @"(?<!\S)\d+(?!\S)"

 (?<! \S )             # Whitespace boundary
 \d+ 
 (?! \S )              # Whitespace boundary
```

You can find integer or decimal numbers on whitespace boundaries like this -

```
 # @"(?<!\S)(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?!\S)"

 (?<! \S )             # Whitespace boundary
 (?:                   # Integer or decimal number
      \d+ 
      (?: \. \d* )?
   |  \. \d+ 
 )
 (?! \S )              # Whitespace boundary
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you said all numbers are seperate by space you could simply do it like this.

```
public static List<int> GetNumbers(string str)
{
    List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
    foreach (data; str.Split(' '))
    {
        int value;
        if (int.TryParse(data, out value))
            numbers.Add(value);
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

Where the passed string (str) is the string that has the numbers in it.

Also if you want to get decimals you can use `double.TryParse()`

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I guess one solution would be to look for substrings where there is no word character.</strike>

So the regular expression would be `^\w+`. Look at http://www.regexr.com/3bfdc.

<strike>EDIT: Answer is not correct as it mathes only beggining non-word. I think the correct solution is to use `\w\d+\w` which really matches all the only digit substrings. See it working correctly [here](http://www.regexr.com/3bfdc).</strike>

Answers were not correct but I think I got the point to match substrings (which have space boundries) where there is no word character. Better solutions were given such as the elegant one for C# and the other one with regex which uses boundries and lookahed and lookbehind.